# Django admin: customizing model creation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have an application for converting media files after user uploads them. After creating `RadioStation` and `Codec` objects within Django admin, and creating `UploadedTrack` I try to add an object of `Track` class. It's possible to do it in admin site, but I'm stuck with two things:
1. get `radiostation` field predefined (its value passed with the uploaded track)
2. ability to select `codec` field value from within 'track/add' page, so that the displayed `codec` options were limited to the given `radiostation`.

```
class RadioStation(models.Model): 
    radiostation = models.CharField()

class Codec(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    bitrate = models.IntegerField()
    radiostation = models.ForeignKey(RadioStation)

class UploadedTrack(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=fs)
    radiostation = models.ForeignKey(RadioStation)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name

class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(UploadedTrack)
    codec = models.ForeignKey(Codec)
    radiostation = models.ForeignKey(RadioStation)
```

Comment: The answer to the 2nd point of your question is `ModelAdmin.inlines`, but I don't quite get the 1st part of the question. There is no `radiostation` field in any of your models. I think what you are looking for is overriding a `models.Model.save()` method

Comment: So you want to have `Track.radiostation` attribute always the same as `radiostation` of its `name` and `codec`?

Comment: Ok, I've renamed the fields. ModelAdmin options allow to display all available codecs, but I need only those related to the given radiostation to be shown and selectable.

Comment: When a user uploads a track he selects the radiostation. For each radiostation I have several codecs. Before processing the uploaded file, I need to create an object of class 'Track' using the user-defined 'radiostation' and selecting its 'codec' options.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't get what's wrong with the code you have. Do you want to limit `codec` choices to only those matching the selected `radiostation`?

Comment: Exactly. For each 'radiostation' I define a separate set of 'codecs'. When creating a new 'track' I take the uploaded file name and its 'radiostation' field and select available 'codecs ' for that 'radiostation'. In other words, I want 'Track.name' and 'Track.radiostation' to be predefined in 'add Track object' page, and choose one of the codecs related to this 'RadioStation'.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but if I get your question right, when you click `Add track` in your Django admin panel, you want it to immediately have predefined `name` and `radiostation` fields? And `codec` field choices limited only to the specified `radiostation`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible, this would be something like reading in mind. The only way I see is to set the `name` to be the last uploaded `UploadedTrack` and `radiostation` to be the `name.radiostation`

Comment: Thank you, Nhor. I believe the only option is to try to customize Django admin views and templates, although it doesn't seem to be easy.

Comment: "I'm not quite sure, but if I get your question right, when you click Add track in your Django admin panel, you want it to immediately have predefined name and radiostation fields? And codec field choices limited only to the specified radiostation?"  - Only 'radiostation' is predifined, 'name' is available from standard admin dropdown list.